# XDocument.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting) tooltip

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

[image]

This might be a naive question. However, I am just trying to understand why the tool tip says "Preserve" when [actually it discards unnecessary white space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.saveoptions.aspx).

Comment: I agree it is confusing. DisableFormatting means: do not indent

Comment: Edit: I agree it is confusing. DisableFormatting means: do not indent. Do not indent means: write all xml on 1 line. This has a side effect of preserve white space. So they describe the side effect, not the effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a misleading double negative here. The documentation you linked to says (emphasis mine):

> If you *do not* disable formatting, then all insignificant white space
>   in the XML tree *is discarded*, and the XML is formatted (indented) as
>   it is serialized.

It means that if `DisableFormatting` *is* specified, insignificant white space will *not* be discarded, i.e. it will be preserved in the serialized output. So, the tooltip is right.